# htaccess redirect a page from root domain to subdomain same name page

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect

on my Wordpress site, I need to

```
http://example.com/page1/
```

redirect to

```
http://site.example.com/page1/
```

I have tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^page1$ "http\:\/\/site\.example\.com\/page1\/" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The above did not work.  I also removed the double quotes and escape slashes and just directly put the url, but no success.  I will really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `http://example.com/page1/`
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^page1$ ....
> ```

You are missing a trailing slash on the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Try the following in the `.htaccess` file at `example.com`'s document root. This will need to go *before* any existing WordPress rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1/$ http://site.example.com/page1/ [R=301,L]
```

> I also removed the double quotes and escape slashes ...

Yes, no need for the plethora of backslash escapes. That looks like one of cPanel's attempts.

Also, no need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper, unless this is expected to "work" without mod_rewrite installed?

The `RewriteBase` directive is also superfluous here. (Note that you should only have one `RewriteBase` directive in your `.htaccess` file - WordPress usually writes this already.)

Comment: This worked.  Thank you so much!  just one question, why this need to be put in before any WordPress rewrites.  When I put it at the end of htaccess it does not work.  I have just put it before `# BEGIN WordPress` tag and it is working fine.

Comment: You're welcome. If you were to put those directives at the end of `.htaccess`, after the WordPress rewrites, then it wouldn't work because it's not being run at all. WP rewrites/routes _all requests_ so any mod_rewrite directives that follow are simply ignored.

Comment: in continuation of my above comments  - `Redirect 301 /hello-world/ http://example.com/` works fine at the end of htaccess. Why such behavior?  Please help me understand.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Different modules run at different times during the request, but directives within each module execute in order, top-down. `Redirect` is part of mod_alias, whereas WP (and the above) uses mod_rewrite. These modules execute independently (mod_rewrite usually first). So, the `Redirect` directive executes regardless of the mod_rewrite directives that precede it. But also, you should never mix external redirects from both modules, because you can end up with unexpected conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this solution by replacing rewrite rule with below line in the .htaccess.

```
Redirect /page1/   http://site.example.com/page1/
```

Comment: This is creating infinite loop.

Comment: It would seem that `example.com` and `site.example.com` share the same filesystem, so you will need to use mod_rewrite and detect the _host_, by which the site has been accessed, before redirecting - you can't do this with a mod_alias `Redirect`.